# Altium Designer '21 error: different modal mode selected

Tags: altium

I am trying to add a line to my schematic library, but when I do so it says Error: Different modal mode selected. The other properties for pins etc are also not displayed properly. I tried closing the program and reopening it in hopes that it would restore the previous settings, but it didn't.

Comment: This is a question and answer site so, you need to ask a question and, hopefully, someone might be able to answer it. Have you tried altium support groups? If not, then why not?

Comment: This would definitely be a question for the Altium forums, especially considering AD21 is a new product that is still in beta.